# How can the elements in the nav bar that lead you to different pages on the same line as the logo?

Tags: html, css, web, nav

So I've gotten the nav bar working and responsive and everything, the only problem is that I want my logo to be larger than the other elements like "contact us, work, services, etc" and when I make it larger, the logo and the other elements aren't on the same line, the other elements are a bit above the logo because it's so big (don't be immature) **is there any way to kinda move the other elements down while keeping it responsive?** here's a link to the website: https://civill-or-home.mksalem2024.repl.co/

here's the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.greenCircle {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #00ff6c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(36%, 30%);
}

header {
  min-height: 14vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.punctuation {
  color: #2ecc71;
}

#logo {
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Civill | Web Design</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="greenCircle"></div>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">Civill<span class="punctuation">.</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're talking about the navigation menu not being centre aligned with the logo once you increase the size of the logo. If you would like to make small adjustments to the menu after you've found the desired sizing for the logo you can do something like this:

```
ul {
width: 40%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
}
```

notice how I have changed the position to relative and that will allow you to use 'top' or you could use 'bottom' instead. you can adjust the placement by changing '5px' to a greater or lower number.

I would only recommend this for small adjustments to get a nice central alignment if your looking to keep it all mobile friendly & clean.

If you would like an alternative method let me know.

Comment: Now that I'm reading this, the answer to this is quite simple, my brain must've turned into mush yesterday after coding for so long. Thanks.